# error while retrieving data from the database

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5

i was trying to display news with its comments, but one of the headlines is giving me an error,but others are working, i have a table of news and i have a table of news_comments, some of the news are being retrieved perfectly with their comments but this one is giving me an error.

[image]

```
@extends('layouts.app')


@section('content')
<div class="container">
  {{$news->title}}<br/>
  @foreach($news->news_pictures as $news_picture)
    <img src="{{asset($news_picture->pictures)}}" width="200"><br/>
    @endforeach
   {!! $news->body !!} <br/>
  <small>written on{{$news->created_at}} by {{$news->user->name}} </small>


</div>


@foreach($news->news_comments as $news_comment)

  @if(!Auth::guest())
    <div class="well">
      <a href="{{action('ProfileController@show', [$news_comment->user->id, $news_comment->user->name])}}">{!! $news_comment->user->name!!}</a>
      {{$news_comment->comments}}<br/>
      {{$news_comment->created_at}}

    </div>
    @else
<div class="well">
  {{$news_comment->commentor}}<br/>
  {{$news_comment->comments}}<br/>
  {{$news_comment->created_at}}
</div>
    @endif

  @endforeach








@if(!Auth::guest())
  <form action="{{action('NewsController@AddComments',[$news->id])}}" method="post">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="container">
      <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="comments" placeholder="your comment"></textarea>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" >post</button>
    </div>
  </form>


  @else
  <form action="{{action('NewsController@AddComments',[$news->id])}}" method="post">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="container">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="your name" name="commentor">
      <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="comments" placeholder="your comment"></textarea>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" >post</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  @endif
@endsection
```

Comment: can you print echo "<pre>"; print_r($news); and post result

Comment: Why do you have controller method as action in link? What do you want to achieve here? `<a href="{{action('ProfileController@show', [$news_comment->user->id, $news_comment->user->name])}}">{!! $news_comment->user->name!!}</a>`

Comment: this error shows that, that property you want to access that doesn't exist try to debug it it might be `null`

Answer (score 0):

This error occur when the property you want to access that doesn't exist so you should check property `isset` or not

Here is the example

```
@if (!is_null($news_comment->user))
    <div class="well">
        <a href="{{action('ProfileController@show', [$news_comment->user->id, $news_comment->user->name])}}">{!! $news_comment->user->name!!}</a>
        {{$news_comment->comments}}<br/>
        {{$news_comment->created_at}}
    </div> 
@endif
```

**OR**

```
@if (isset($news_comment->user->id) && isset($news_comment->user->name))
    <div class="well">
        <a href="{{action('ProfileController@show', [$news_comment->user->id, $news_comment->user->name])}}">{!! $news_comment->user->name!!}</a>
        {{$news_comment->comments}}<br/>
        {{$news_comment->created_at}}
    </div> 
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use: with `()` on `user`

```
<a href="{{action('ProfileController@show', [$news_comment->user()->id, $news_comment->user()->name])}}">{!! $news_comment->user()->name!!}</a>
```

Instead of:

```
<a href="{{action('ProfileController@show', [$news_comment->user->id, $news_comment->user->name])}}">{!! $news_comment->user->name!!}</a>
```